# Eliminate a specific label data in a graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

[Data_frame_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FERpw.png)I am trying to build a barplot, but I have an issue with the labels.

The graph's dataframe source is not grouped for the bar category "Otros", regarding that I am getting several labels in that bar (I want just one label with the total sum of "Otros")

[image]

I addition I need the bars in an descendant order in the graph excepting the "Otros" bar which I need in the last place (Bottom)

```
Cred_by_Prod<-structure(list(cultivo = c("GANADERIA CARNE", "SERVICIOS DE APOYO", 
                           "ARROZ", "CAFÉ", "CAÑA DE AZUCAR", "AVICULTURA", "PALMA", "GANADERIA LECHE", 
                           "FRUTALES", "OTROS CULTIVOS (Ciclo corto+Perennes)", "ACTIVIDAD MIXTA AGROPECUARIA RURAL", 
                           "PORCICULTURA", "CACAO", "PAPA", "BANANO", "PLATANO", "FLORES", 
                           "HORTALIZAS", "AGUACATE", "ALGODÓN", "CAÑA PANALERA", "MAIZ", 
                           "FORESTALES", "ACUICULTURA", "CITRICOS", "ACTIVIDADES RURALES", 
                           "TABACO", "OTROS PECUARIOS + APICULTURA", "YUCA", "CAUCHO", "ACTIVIDADES NO CLASIFICADAS"
), gr_sum = c(28.3254536384453, 22.4779943084809, 17.3083119473968, 
              16.5173053124414, 13.512530394183, 11.2419739653207, 9.8645607723738, 
              9.15579319695601, 6.21764754430497, 6.0597093441194, 3.40838697587753, 
              2.91394799943291, 2.530961953157, 2.250675318187, 2.248310268646, 
              1.915656141584, 1.80467388350462, 1.782433571294, 1.729078557108, 
              1.708796392104, 1.585391516969, 1.546049716909, 1.501875611076, 
              1.474594244825, 0.911062924627, 0.805293685917, 0.663811759298, 
              0.386514092089, 0.363622531613, 0.28208629398177, 0.042880323094
), prop = c(0.164169949441345, 0.130278979333187, 0.100316299734825, 
            0.0957317475886894, 0.0783165367783116, 0.0651567428033229, 0.0571734689206754, 
            0.0530655616473361, 0.0360365237578125, 0.035121138370864, 0.0197544838874844, 
            0.0168887920330538, 0.014669064128378, 0.0130445661316485, 0.0130308586702066, 
            0.0111028467866794, 0.0104596107795762, 0.0103307093689305, 0.0100214719567723, 
            0.00990391966455597, 0.00918868408985608, 0.00896066509996723, 
            0.00870463881301742, 0.00854652023263082, 0.00528037983726739, 
            0.00466735768436169, 0.00384735031443982, 0.00224017591268139, 
            0.00210749996778928, 0.00163492854208797, 0.000248527722246814
), prop_acum = c(0.164169949441345, 0.294448928774532, 0.394765228509357, 
                 0.490496976098046, 0.568813512876357, 0.63397025567968, 0.691143724600356, 
                 0.744209286247692, 0.780245810005504, 0.815366948376368, 0.835121432263853, 
                 0.852010224296907, 0.866679288425285, 0.879723854556933, 0.89275471322714, 
                 0.903857560013819, 0.914317170793395, 0.924647880162326, 0.934669352119098, 
                 0.944573271783654, 0.95376195587351, 0.962722620973477, 0.971427259786495, 
                 0.979973780019126, 0.985254159856393, 0.989921517540755, 0.993768867855195, 
                 0.996009043767876, 0.998116543735665, 0.999751472277753, 1), 
Cat_top = c("GANADERIA CARNE", "SERVICIOS DE APOYO", "ARROZ", 
            "CAFÉ", "CAÑA DE AZUCAR", "AVICULTURA", "PALMA", "GANADERIA LECHE", 
            "FRUTALES", "OTROS CULTIVOS (Ciclo corto+Perennes)", "Otros", 
            "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
            "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", 
            "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros", "Otros")), row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                  -31L), class = "data.frame")

Cred_by_Prod%>%
  mutate(Cat_top = fct_reorder(Cat_top,gr_sum)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Cat_top,y=gr_sum))+ #graficando cred por producto 2000-2021
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=.6, width=.4)+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(title="Colocaciones Finagro por Producto 2000-2021",
       x="Cultivo",y="Billones $COP")+
  geom_label(label=round(Cred_by_Prod$gr_sum,1),nudge_x=0.1, nudge_y=-1,
                                                 check_overlap=T,label.padding=unit(0.1, "lines"),
                                                 label.size=0.0001,
                                                 color="black")+
  geom_label(label=paste(round(Cred_by_Prod$prop*100,1),"%"),nudge_x=0.1, nudge_y=2,
             check_overlap=TRUE,
             color="black",size=3)
```

I really appreciate your help. I am new in R

Comment: Sorry. I dont have any previous experience in stack ( i sing up today) AND also i am starting user in R.

Comment: Can you show the output of `dput(Cred_by_Prod)`?

Comment: Hello Julien. Thanks, I've just added a Dataframe "Cred_by_Prod" Image.

Comment: If it is not possible to obtain a single label in the "others" bar, ¿how could I eliminate the labels that the "Otros" bar now has?

Comment: If your post, can you include the output from `dput(Cred_by_Prod)`? We can't reproduce your issue with an image.

Comment: @jrcalabrese I just learned what dput is (very useful thanks). Now the section code in the post has the dput's result.

Comment: "In addition I need the bars in an descendant order in the graph excepting the "Otros" bar which I need in the last place (Bottom)" : isn't that what is shown in the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an option using `group_by` and `summarize` within the pipe leading to ggplot:

```
Cred_by_Prod%>%
  mutate(Cat_top = fct_reorder(Cat_top,gr_sum)) %>% 
  group_by(Cat_top) %>% 
  summarize(gr_sum = sum(gr_sum))

# A tibble: 11 x 2
   Cat_top                               gr_sum
   <fct>                                  <dbl>
 1 Otros                                  31.9 
 2 OTROS CULTIVOS (Ciclo corto+Perennes)   6.06
 3 FRUTALES                                6.22
 4 GANADERIA LECHE                         9.16
 5 PALMA                                   9.86
 6 AVICULTURA                             11.2 
 7 CAÑA DE AZUCAR                         13.5 
 8 CAFÉ                                   16.5 
 9 ARROZ                                  17.3 
10 SERVICIOS DE APOYO                     22.5 
11 GANADERIA CARNE                        28.3
```

Then you need to specify the label in `aes` in `geom_label`

```
Cred_by_Prod%>%
  mutate(Cat_top = fct_reorder(Cat_top,gr_sum)) %>% 
  group_by(Cat_top) %>% 
  summarize(gr_sum = sum(gr_sum)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Cat_top,y=gr_sum))+ #graficando cred por producto 2000-2021
  geom_bar(stat="identity", alpha=.6, width=.4)+
  theme_bw()+
  coord_flip()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))+
  labs(title="Colocaciones Finagro por Producto 2000-2021",
       x="Cultivo",y="Billones $COP")+
  geom_label(aes(label=round(gr_sum,1)),nudge_x=0.1, nudge_y=-1,
             check_overlap=T,label.padding=unit(0.1, "lines"),
             label.size=0.0001,
             color="black")
```

[image]